# Razor view not generating href for Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I currently have a .net core web app (.Net core 3.1) using the Razor Pages. I have the following folder structure.

```
Areas (folder)
  Users (folder)
     Pages (folder)
       Index.cshtml
       Edit.cshtml
```

Inside the Index.cshtml I have the view code below. When the application is running it is not generating an href and when I check the html it generates the html as below:

```html
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Users" asp-page="/Edit" asp-route-id="56591c1d-88af-48b6-b41b-1948af412511">Edit</a>
```

```
@page
@model MyApp.Areas.User.Pages.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Users";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Users</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Operations</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Users" asp-page="/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.UserId">Edit</a> |
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was missing **_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@using MyApp.Areas.Users
@using MyApp.Areas.Users.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```